# Deleting Files from Secondary BTSync Client Files remain in Ubuntu VPS but invisible

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, storage, bittorrent-sync

I installed BTSync on my VPS which is running Ubuntu 13.10. I set up a drop folder where I would transfer my files & that would sync to my home PC. I would then delete things on my home PC (not the primary device- which is my VPS) and if I ls -la it would show folder as empty. Yesterday I found out that I was using 99% of my storage. There was an existing file which was not deleted. So I deleted it via SSH and it cleared the space- but I'm still using 60% of my VPS's storage despite only being at 5% before I began making transfers this way.

Is it possible to find these files despite them no longer being listed in the folder? I've tried looking through SuperUser and other sites but I can't find the answer. i even asked my ubuntu certed friend and he had no idea.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is DO NOT delete remotely. Doing so deletes the remote file, and it appears the pointer to the local file that was backed up. A simple LS showed all my files still there, only hidden.

Sorry I totally forgot I posted this question until now.